# how to use a constructor function's output to insert values to an object?

Tags: javascript, oop

I created a constructor function for a circle with one radius value, and two functions to calculate area and perimeter, I am trying to pass the calculated value of area and perimeter as elements of the object to be constructed but it's not working.

```
    function Circle (r) {
        this.radius = r;
        this.area = function () {
            var a =  Math.PI * this.radius * this.radius;
            // tried this 
            this.areaaaa = a;

        };



        this.perimeter = function(){
            var p =  Math.PI * this.radius * 2;
            // tried this too
            this.perimeterrrr = p;

            };



    };

    var x = new Circle(5);

    console.log(x);

    // output is {radius:5, area: [function], perimeter: [function]}

// desired output is {radius:5, area: [function],areaaa:78.54, perimeter: [function], perimeterrrr:31.42}
```

Comment: But why? Your object will have inconsistent values if you change radius later.

Comment: Right now, you're defining methods called `area` and `perimeter` but you never call those methods. Do you actually want them to be getters?

Comment: I think you didn't get my point, all I want to do is to pass the calculated value of area and perimeter as another object value in an automated way rather than typing manually for each calculated value

Comment: @apsillers yes I want to them to be getters and calculators as well, if that makes sense

Comment: @aspillers check my desired output if what I said didn't make sense

Answer (score 4):

You can use [ECMA 6 getters and setters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get)

```
function Circle (r) {
    this.radius = r;
    Object.defineProperty(this, "area", { get: function () { return Math.PI * this.radius * this.radius; } })

};

var circle = new Circle(5)
circle.radius //5
circle.area  //78.53981633974483
```

Comment: Just a note: `Object.defineProperty` has existed since ES5; this is not a new ES6 feature.

Comment: @apsillers thanks for that Info! the docs are confusing then `Starting with ECMAScript 6, you can also use expressions for a computed property name to bind to the given function.` I guess they mean the `{get: ` key that uses the function as a value property

Comment: That refers to the `{ get prop() { ... } }` syntax on object literals, not anything to do with `Object.defineProperty`. ES6 allows you to use runtime-computed property names on object literals.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that the code inside those function definitions is never being run. Try this.

```
function Circle (r) {
    this.radius = r;
    this.a = Math.PI * this.radius * this.radius;
    this.p = Math.PI * this.radius * 2;
};

var x = new Circle(5);

console.log(x);
```

Comment: I don't understand what is meant by the code in those function never being run, and how do I run them if so?

Comment: @Adam It means that you don't run the functions. Imagine if you never did `new Circle(5)`. Would you expect the code in `Circle` to run without you telling it to run? You have to run the functions, or else the code inside of them does not run.

Comment: For the lines inside of this.area and this.perimeter to be run, you would need to add a call to `x.area` or `x.perimeter` after `var x = new Circle(5)`. After that, x.areaaaa and x.perimeterrrr would be set.

Comment: What will happen if i'll do `x.radius = 9`? the `a` and `p` won't update. these properties should be calculated during the get method

Comment: Thanks Shaun and apsillers for the helpful explanation